How to show color image from kinect azure in Unity?
I'm using kinect azure to develop body tracking project in Unity.
However, the sample script (SkeletalTrackingProvider.cs) seems just passing depth image data. May I ask how to get color data?
In SkeletalTrackingProvider.cs, I change from:
device.StartCameras(new DeviceConfiguration()
{
     CameraFPS = FPS.FPS30,
     ColorResolution = ColorResolution.Off,
     DepthMode = DepthMode.NFOV_Unbinned,
     WiredSyncMode = WiredSyncMode.Standalone
});

to
device.StartCameras(new DeviceConfiguration()
{
    CameraFPS = FPS.FPS30,
    ColorResolution = ColorResolution.R1080p,
    DepthMode = DepthMode.NFOV_Unbinned,
    WiredSyncMode = WiredSyncMode.Standalone,
    ColorFormat = ImageFormat.ColorBGRA32
});

and then adding:
if (bodyFrameCapture.Color != null)
{
    Microsoft.Azure.Kinect.Sensor.Image colorImage = bodyFrameCapture.Color;
    var colorFrame = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ushort>(colorImage.Memory.Span);
    currentFrameData.ColorImageWidth = colorImage.WidthPixels;
    currentFrameData.ColorImageHeight = colorImage.HeightPixels;

    int colorCounter = 0;
    currentFrameData.ColorImageSize = currentFrameData.ColorImageWidth * currentFrameData.ColorImageHeight * 4;
    for (int it = currentFrameData.ColorImageWidth * currentFrameData.ColorImageHeight - 1; it > 0; it--)
    {
        byte b = (byte)(colorFrame[it] / (ConfigLoader.Instance.Configs.SkeletalTracking.MaximumDisplayedDepthInMillimeters) * 255);
        currentFrameData.ColorImage[colorCounter++] = b;  // Maybe wrong here
        currentFrameData.ColorImage[colorCounter++] = b;  // Maybe wrong here
        currentFrameData.ColorImage[colorCounter++] = b;  // Maybe wrong here
        currentFrameData.ColorImage[colorCounter++] = 255;
    }
}

which almost same code of getting depth data.
Although I can show image after loading color byte array data into RawImage, but the color is wrong(just black and white), so I want to know what is correct method passing data into byte array.

Try using GetPixels() on the colorImage.  Just a note, setting the same byte to each of the color components will always result in a greyscale value.

Although I'm not exactly know what is the different, but I change
var colorFrame = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ushort>(colorImage.Memory.Span);

to
var colorFrame = colorImage.Memory.Span;

And thanks for @hijinxbassist point out my mistake of inputing same value to r g b
for (int it = 0; it < currentFrameData.ColorImageWidth * currentFrameData.ColorImageHeight; it++)
{
    currentFrameData.ColorImage[colorCounter++] = (byte)(colorFrame[it * 4]);  // Blue
    currentFrameData.ColorImage[colorCounter++] = (byte)(colorFrame[it * 4 + 1]);  // Green
    currentFrameData.ColorImage[colorCounter++] = (byte)(colorFrame[it * 4 + 2]);  // Red
    currentFrameData.ColorImage[colorCounter++] = 255;  // Alpha
}

Now it's work.
